# Thermal Expansion: Given $T$, what is the stress gradient and its divergence?

Tags: temperature, differentiation, elasticity, stress-strain, differential-equations

Given the temperature distribution (i.e. $T(x)$ in 1D) across a metal line, what the are the expressions for the stress gradient (i.e. $\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x}$ in 1D) and its divergence (i.e.  $\frac{\partial^2 \sigma}{\partial x ^2}$)?

---

My own effort (which might be wrong):

- I think the divergence of the stress gradient is: $\frac{\partial^2 \sigma}{\partial x ^2}=\frac{2E}{3(v-1)}\alpha\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x ^2}$. Is this correct?
- What about the gradient itself? Can I simply take the integral from previous part and say: $\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x}=\frac{2E}{3(v-1)}\alpha\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}+(\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x}(x=0)-\frac{2E}{3(v-1)}\alpha\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}(x=0))$?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind It is not a homework-like question. I'm dealing with elasticity and wondering how to obtain those quantity. Prefer conceptual question? It is a conceptual confusion, indeed, for me.I did not even asked for explicit expressions. I'm conceptually asking how to drive those or what they look like.  Can you please now remove the hold or help instead?

Comment: What is the definition of a "metal line?"

Comment: @ChesterMiller A 1D structure made of metal.

Comment: Is the bar constrained axially so it can't expand?

Comment: @ChesterMiller yes, rigidly.

Comment: If the bar is in equilibrium, then the divergence of the stress tensor should be zero.  When thermal expansion is involved, the stress tensor has a linear contribution from the strains and a superimposed linear (isotropic) contribution from the temperature change.  In some developments, the two contributions are separated, and the part due only to the strains is referred to as "the stress tensor."  Is that what your sources have done?